# cURL do not mimic click

Tags: plugins, ajax

Another plugin has set a function where is triggered when you click a link for example "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bla&other_arg=bla2"
When you click the link, a pdf is generated and downloaded, I want to mimic the click, in my code, as the file echoed I want to capture it. But using cURL or wp_remote_get, results in nothing. No errors occur but the function is never triggered. I have placed error_logging in the function. Clicking a link "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bla&other_arg=bla2" is working but using wp_remote_get("http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bla&other_arg=bla2"), does nothing, same with cURL

Comment: Be more specific, also provide code.  Are you just trying to call a function that lives in another plugin?

Comment: I am not trying to call the function directly as the function takes no arguments directly and the variables are set in the class.

Comment: You could try copying the user's cookies into the wp_request_get to see if the problem is authentication. But I think you're going to have to debug the function you're calling to see why it's going wrong. Or better still refactor it to expose the parts you want to call and call them directly.